# Create Panda Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a loop to find the following Dataframe for 'ABC', 'DEF','GHI','JKR'.

```
list = ['ABC', 'DEF','GHI','JKR']
for i in list:
  dataframe1 = xxxxxxxxx Some Code xxxxxxxxx
```

Get the following data frames in this loop for the above list

[image: Dataframe]

I want to create a new panda data frame as follows by getting data in above dataframe.

[image: New Dataframe]

Note:

- Each row adds when for loop go through each item of the list.
- Above the first data frame can have multiple data for the same month so add using comma.
- Values are above the first data frame Divided column. Month gets by above the first data frame Date column. `pd.DatetimeIndex(dataframe1['Date']).strftime('%B')`
- If possible, apply red color to value, when values are from today date and also highlight current month column.

I tried to use the following code but it is not working also it is adding new data frames for the loop.

```
pd.crosstab(dataframe1['Type'],pd.DatetimeIndex(dataframe1['Date']).strftime('%B'),dataframe1['Dividend'], aggfunc=','.join)
```

Comment: Can you please add the code to constuct the dataframe you used in your example? Please also add the names (abc, ect) and all other info, that is required to produce the output, this way it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I have no idea how to code it

Comment: I can't aggregate the contents of the list because there is no relevance between the contents of the list and the data you presented. The data does not have a name column.

Comment: @r-beginners because ABC has one dataframe like a fist, DEF has one dataframe and so on.